# Controller doesn't generate by using console

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning the framework *Symfony* and try to create a controller with the binary tool Symfony on cmd by using command

```
symfony console make:controllers
```

I get success in console, but the file controller doesn't exist. The controller hasn't been generated. Why ?

Comment: Two things to consider when asking a question.  1. Make sure what you post is accurate.  make:controllers will generate an error.  2. Try and give more or less complete info.  make:controller kicks off a dialog.  Posting the dialog (with proper formatting) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure make:controllers is working ? to generate controller you need to use in SF 5 *php bin/console make:controller* you can find more on https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html

Comment: Just for info, "symfony console" is equivalent to "php bin/console".  And besides that rather unfortunate misunderstanding, you really should consider posting an actual answer if you can figure out what the actual problem is from the question.